# The Joy of TeX ...

Tags: books, tex-history

I didn't know where to put this question, so I put it in Meta.

For those that know this book by M. SPIVAK, which edition, 1982, 1983, 1986, 1990 does the E, Eir, Em *first* appear in?

Just interested :)

The question is for those that actually had (have?) the physical copies of these editions.

Comment: One of the best software manuals ever written.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

the use of "e", "eir", "em" was in the first draft of *joy*, pre-publication.

(i did much of the production work on the book, including helping to
create the code for formatting the index, so i don't even have to look.)